# What are the orange plates on Picard's desk?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, jean-luc-picard, object-identification

As you can see in the below image and, as I'm sure most *TNG* watchers would have noticed, there are a series of orange 'plates' on Picard's desk.  Does anyone know what these are? (Does Picard ever use them or talk about what they are?)

[image]

Comment: On occasion he types on them as if they are pads.

Comment: They're the ignition keys for the Enterprise...

Comment: I came here to see in what episode Picard's ready room featured some plates of oranges.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper, [this one](http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/memoryalpha/images/6/65/Rotten_fruits.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20120629133854&path-prefix=en) from "Timescape" ?

Comment: @ThePopMachine: Good find, although those are not on Picard's desk.

Comment: **In deference to the rules of Stack Exchange, I’m stating this is only my own made up idea for fun, not any kind of fact.** My headcanon says they’re large isolinear chips from the Stargazer. Possibly part of the assembly used during the Picard Maneuver. Or containing old Captain’s Logs from the ship. Just a nice memento from his first command.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

## No official in-universe use, but they should be data storage devices according to Michael and Denise Okuda

**I asked Michael and Denise Okuda (*TNG* production and art designers) this question ten minutes ago at the Star Trek 50th Anniversary Celebration in Las Vegas.**

> **MICHAEL:** That's a *darn* good question.

He then explained that, out-of-universe, these orange plates are **props left over from *The Motion Picture***.  Circuit designs were painted on them for *TNG*.

In-universe, he said that no specific function had ever been assigned to the plates.  There was talk at one point amongst production personnel and/or set designers that they might serve as PADD-style devices (data display devices or readers, but smaller and thinner than PADDs).  **But he insisted that no official purpose had ever been assigned to them by any designers or writers.  He did say that, in retrospect, they should probably be data storage devices.**

> **DENISE:** They were just something for Picard to play with!

Comment: Okay this is absolutely bounty worthy!  Brilliant work!

Comment: Thanks!  I've been waiting a whole year to ask them this!  :-D

Comment: @OftenRight : I appreciate the generous bounty!

Comment: the answer was most deserving. Outstanding job once again!

Comment: Every captain needs desk toys.

Answer (score 19):

They look like giant isolinear chips or circuit boards.

I can't find any documentation on those exact ones, but these pretty-similar-looking ones from *ST VI* and *ST VII* are referred to as isolinear chips in a plexiglass isolinear chip holder:
[image: Similar-looking translucent sky blue (3), hot orange (5), and yellow (1) isolinear chips mounted upright on a clear plexiglass stand.]

The ones on Picard's desk in *TNG* have more rounded corners, but they have roughly the same design.

You can see some slightly smaller and more conventional-looking isolinear chips on Troi's desk here:
[image: Frontal shot of Counselor Troi's light tan and white desk in front of her tan high-back chair. A PADD, a smaller screened device and some loose isolinear chips ranging from the small flat-stick-shaped to a couple of much larger ones are scattered on the desk. An isolinear chip holder is shown on the left side, with 4 or 5 largish square chips resting in it.]

Here are some more from Picard's Enterprise-E ready room that are used in *First Contact*, *Nemesis* and *Generations*:
[image: Three isolinear chip holders holding a dozen large square and rectangular isolinear chips with 3 loose rectangular chips. Some are blue, others are green, yellow and hot orange.]
[image: Picard in the Enterprise-E ready room with 5 or 6 PADDs laying on his desk. Two isolinear chip holders are to his left, another is on sitting on a shelf behind to the right of him.]

Picard is seen holding a stylus or circuit-diagnostic/repair device to one of these plates in one episode. So they might be more like circuit boards or interactive e-readers than simply storage devices.

Comment: Cool. Now where do I get those?

Comment: The actual TV/film props cost a pretty penny: http://www.icollector.com/Marina-Sirtis-Counselor-Troi-isolinear-chips-from-her-quarters-from-Star-Trek-First-Contact_i10031006 (sold for $650)
http://www.liveauctioneers.com/item/7457717 (sold for $400~600)
http://www.icollector.com/3-STAR-TREK-ENTERPRISE-ISOLINEAR-CHIPS-HOLDERS_i13362736 (sold for $8000) But you can find fan reproductions for a lot cheaper on eBay.

Comment: Yeah, well, not in germany, I'm afraid -.-

Comment: So, high-tech versions of the floppy disk?  (The timing is certainly right..)